# LXML: get text inbetween elements children

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have a badly structured html template, where my `<section>` elements contain multiple elements (p, figure, a, etc), but also raw text in between. How can I access all those snippets of texts, and edit them in place (what I need is to replace all `$$code$$` with  tags?)
both `section.text` and `section.tail` return empty strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the `.tail` of the complete tag that immediately precedes the text. So, in `<section>A<p>B</p>C<p>D</p>E</section>`, the `.tail`s of the two `<p>` elemnts will contain C and E.

Example:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring('<root><section>A<p>B</p>C<p>D</p>E</section></root>')

for section_child in root.find('section'):
    section_child.tail = section_child.tail.lower()

print(etree.tounicode(root))
```

Result:

```xml
<root><section>A<p>B</p>c<p>D</p>e</section></root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I learnt from the answer in my posted question: [Parse XML text in between elements within a root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52660860/parse-xml-text-in-between-elements-within-a-root-element)

```
from lxml import etree


xml = '<a>aaaa1<b>bbbb</b>aaaa2<c>cccc</c>aaaa3</a>'
element = etree.fromstring(xml)
for text in element.xpath('text()'):
    xml = xml.replace(f'>{text}<', f'>{text.upper()}<')
```

One concern for this is regarding CDATA in xml, but I would guess this is not an issue for html.