# Parse XML text in between elements within a root element

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse XML in Python. Here is the sample of the XML structure:

```
<a>aaaa1
 <b>bbbb</b>aaaa2
 <c>cccc</c>aaaa3
</a>
```

It is seen that for root tree a, it has text "aaaa1", "aaaa2" is between tree b and c, and "aaaa3" is between c and inside a. I would like to extract the text in a way that "a": {"aaaa1", "aaaa2", "aaaa3"}, "b": {"bbbb"}, "c": {"cccc"}.

This is just a sample, so the depth/tags/nodes can be more complicated, so regex or xpath may not work.
I have used Element.text, Element.itertext() and Element.tail, but "aaaa2" will be seen as the tail for b, and "aaaa3" will be seen as the tail for c. Is there any method to generally put the text in the above-mentioned manner?

```
xml = '<a>aaaa1<b>bbbb</b>aaaa2<c>cccc</c>aaaa3</a>'
parser = XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
element = etree.fromstring(xml, parser)
for text in element.itertext():
    print(text)
for text in element.itertext(tag='a'):
    print(text)
for child in element.getchildren():
    print(child.tag, child.text, child.tail)
```

Temporarily I am trying to identify all text fields for element a through the following method which combines both text with tails from children elements:

```
text_iter = itertools.chain([element.text], (child.tail for child in element.iterchildren()))
text_iter = (text for text in text_iter if isinstance(text, str))
```

Since I am not really familiar with XML schema structure and the standard, not sure if this would always work, and if there is any other better solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that collect text nodes that are direct child of a given parent element:

```
def read_element(e):
    return {e.tag: [t.strip() for t in e.xpath("text()")]}
```

Then call that function on every element in the XML and print the result in the desired format, for example:

```
print(read_element(element))
for e in element.iterdescendants():
    print(read_element(e))
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks neater and much safer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**:  I would like to extract the text in a way that `"a": {"aaaa1", "aaaa2", "aaaa3"}, "b": {"bbbb"}, "c": {"cccc"}`.

---

> **Note**: If there are more than **one** tag `<b>` or `<c>` within `xml`, you have to handle this using a condition!

```
import lxml.etree as etree

xml = '<a>aaaa1<b>bbbb</b>aaaa2<c>cccc</c>aaaa3</a>'

# Parse xml to tree
tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
#root = tree.getroot()

# In this example, the first tag is the root Element
root = tree.tag

# Init result dict with this first Element tag:[text]
result = {tree.tag:[tree.text]}

# Loop every Element in the tree
for element in tree:
    # Add this element to result tag:text
    result.setdefault(element.tag, element.text)

    # If this element has a .tail, append it to the root:[]
    if element.tail:
        result[root].append(element.tail)

print("result:{}".format(result))
>>>result:{'c': 'cccc', 'b': 'bbbb', 'a': ['aaaa1', 'aaaa2', 'aaaa3']}
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***